# Grails 3.3, which transactional library to import?

Tags: grails, import, transactional

If you create a new service groovy class, and add "@Transactional" at the top, eclipse offers 3 imports:

1. grails.transaction.Transactional
2. org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
3. grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional

The first one is what gets created in 3.3 when you generate the static controllers, so one might assume this is the official and correct version. however, it is deprecated.

The middle one is used in some online examples.

The last one is used in [this document](http://docs.grails.org/2.3.11/guide/services.html) page for grails 2.5, so may or may not still be correct.

Does anyone know which is the correct one?

Answer (score 4):

With Grails 3.3 and Gorm 6.x onwards, you should use grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional -- this is replacement for the previous transactional annotations, the old annotations will eventually be removed

Answer (score 3):

`grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional` is GORM 6.1 I think this is  Grails 3.2  + (possibly later releases of 3.2)

`grails.transaction.Transactional` is what i use at the moment and came out in later versions of grails 2

`org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` is the eldest of the lot probably not a good idea to use

In regards to the order that is all down to your IDE, meaning if you select one over another it will in the future remember that and show that to you first